# Swift: DateFormatter me regresa nil en la fecha

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo el siguiente codigo para transformar un string a un Date:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let stringData = formatter.date(from: "2024-02-20 10:24:12")
return stringData!
```

pero el codigo me produce siempre nil, solo quitando la parte de la hora es que obtengo el objecto Date con los datos transformados.
Algunas variantes que he probado es configurando el `timeZone`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
formatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
let stringData = formatter.date(from: "2024-02-20 10:24:12")
return stringData!
```

pero obtengo el mismo resultado, lo curioso es que no en todos los modelos de iphone pasa eso, y otra cosa curiosa el simulador(iPhone 15 - 17.0.1) también produce el error, alguna idea de que puede estar pasando o me falte por configurar?

**(Edit)**
La función completa actualmente la tengo así:

```
static func stringToFullDate(date: String) -> Date{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let stringData = formatter.date(from: date)
    return stringData!
}
```

y al parecer funciona tomando la parte de la hora también, pero no se si deba hacerlo de esa manera, no se si afecte el uso en otros usos horarios por estar específicamente configurado para "en_US"

Comment: Agregue: `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` parece que así funciona pero ¿no se si es correcto hacerlo de esa manera?

Comment: La función enviando como parámetro `"2024-02-20 10:24:12"` funciona bien y de igual manera sin el `Locale`. Qué valor estás enviando a la función para que te devuelva `nil`?

Comment: Ese mismo que puse de ejemplo: `"2024-02-20 10:24:12"` para evitar que algo en medio cambiara lo puse directo, pero ni así. En un iphone X (16.5) me funciona bien pero en otros iphone como un 15 me reportaron el problema, aunque otro iphone 15 no pasa, y logre replicarlo en el simulador, pero no se si sea por la versión de iOS es bastante raro.

Comment: Si envías otra fecha `"12-31-2024"` te va a dar un crash porque estás haciendo unwrap de un valor directamente con `stringData!`. El problema reportado desde el iPhone 15 fue desde TestFlight? o la app en el AppStore? De dónde obtienes las fechas que envías a la función? Cómo sabes que envías el formato correcto de la fecha?

Comment: El crash reportado fue de una instalación del appstore, y efectivamente el error se produce por tratar de hacer el 'unwrap' de un opcional nulo, que no debería ser nulo ya que la fecha que obtengo de un servidor tiene el formato correcto: `"2024-02-20 10:24:12"` ya hice debuggin sobre la app y al momento de ejecutar: `let stringData = formatter.date(from: date)` el valor de `date` es la fecha mencionada y al ejecutar esa línea el resultado es `nil`

Comment: Dentro del AppStore Connect o en Xcode puedes acceder al crash log para ver si hay acceso a la fecha que provocó el crash.

Comment: No hay reporte de errores en appstore connect, al parecer no enviaron ninguno, solo reportaron el error, aun así aunque no pueda tener la fecha exacta que provoco el error en el iphone 15, el error es consistente con cualquier fecha que incluya la hora, como el caso de `"2024-02-20 10:24:12"` replicado en el simulador con (iPhone 15 - 17.0.1) incluso con una fecha establecida manualmente y no la que se obtiene del servidor.
Por el momento lo voy a dejar con la linea `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` para que no falle, pero investigare los detalles con diferentes horarios